# How do Implement the copy constructor for my custom c++ class

Tags: c++, string

I am creating a string class and I have set up my default constructor. I want to know how to go about setting up the copy constructor.

I have already tried the default constructor and the c string constructor. I am confused on what I should do next.

```
DSString::DSString()
{
    data = nullptr;
}

DSString::DSString(const char* d)
{
    data = new char[strlen(d) + 1];
    strcpy(data,d);
}

DSString::DSString(const DSString&)
{
}
```

I expect the result to be functional. but it is not functional right now.

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::string` instead?

Comment: You just need to copy the member variable data

Comment: Just don't. Use string, vector... and avoid direct usage of new/delete. No explicit definitions of copy/destruction operations will be necessary.

Comment: @prog-fh this is probably some kind of exercise. Inside a class whose sole purpose is to manage some dynamic memory there is nothing wrong with `new` and `delete`

Comment: For those telling him to use more advanced classes -- if he's asking questions like this it's because he's learning the language, and knowing how to implement these things is a valuable lesson.

Comment: @JosephLarson `std::string` is *less* advanced (simpler *and* safer to use) than `new` and `delete`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You can pick whatever semantics you want. Understanding how string might work under the hood is a useful exercise. He's learning the language. This is an excellent example for learning about memory management.

Comment: @JosephLarson I'm specifically addressing the *"For those telling him to use more advanced classes"* part of your comment. `std::string` should never be regarded as an "advanced" part of the language.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux which is why I told you to feel free to use whatever semantics makes you feel better. People telling him not to perform what is a perfectly legitimate exercise to learn the language are missing the point that he's trying to learn the language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the same kind of initialization in your `DSString&` copy constructor that you do in your `char*` converting constructor, simply use the `data` member of the input `DSString` as the `char*` to copy from, eg:

```cpp
DSString::DSString(const char *d)
{
    // the behavior of strlen() and strcpy() are undefined if d is null...
    if (d)
    {
        data = new char[strlen(d) + 1];
        strcpy(data, d);
    }
    else
        data = nullptr;
}

DSString::DSString(const DSString &src)
{
    // the behavior of strlen() and strcpy() are undefined if src.data is null...
    if (src.data)
    {
        data = new char[strlen(src.data) + 1];
        strcpy(data, src.data);
    }
    else
        data = nullptr;
}
```

Or, since you are clearly using C++11 or later (by virtue of the use of `nullptr`), you can simply have your copy constructor delegate to your converting constructor itself to avoid repeating code:

```cpp
DSString::DSString(const DSString &src)
    : DSString(src.data)
{
}
```

Don't forget to also include a destructor, a move constructor, a copy assignment operator, and a move assignment operator, per the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three):

```cpp
DSString::DSString(DSString &&src)
    : DSString()
{
    //std::swap(data, src.data);
    data = src.data;
    src.data = nullptr;
}

DSString::~DSString()
{
    delete[] data;
}

DSString& DSString::operator=(const DSString &rhs)
{
    if (&rhs != this)
    {
        DSString tmp(rhs);
        //std::swap(data, tmp.data);
        char *d = data;
        data = tmp.data;
        tmp.data = d;
    }
    return *this;
}

DSString& DSString::operator=(DSString &&rhs)
{
    DSString tmp(std::move(rhs));
    //std::swap(data, tmp.data);
    char *d = data;
    data = tmp.data;
    tmp.data = d;
    return *this;
}
```

Now, that being said, if you were to use `std::string` instead of `char*` for your `data` member (as you should), you get most of this functionality *for free* from the compiler, you don't have to implement it manually, except for the `char*` converting constructor:

```cpp
class DSString
{
private:
    std::string data;
public:
    DSString() = default;
    DSString(const char *d) : data(d ? d : "") {}
    DSString(const DSString&) = default;
    DSString(DSString&&) = default;
    ~DSString() = default;
    DSString& operator=(const DSString&) = default;
    DSString& operator=(DSString&&) = default;
};
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm curious, why did you add self-assignment protection to the copy assignment, but not to the move assignment? Both should work fine without one.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Actually, the move assignment operator DOES have self-assignment protection, it is just implicit via the `tmp` variable, and the fact that self-assignment is almost never performed via a move assignment to begin with

Comment: *"DOES have [implicit] self-assignment protection"* I think same applies to the copy assignment. (even if it didn't have the `if (&rhs != this)`, that is)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat technically yes, having the copy assignment operator use `tmp` unconditionally would also provide self-assignment protection, but removing the self-assignment check forces a copy to *always* be made unconditionally, which may be costly. The explicit check avoids a self copy. The same issue does not exist in move assignment. Anyway, under C++11 and later, a better choice is usually to merge copy assignment and move assignment into a single operator that takes input by value and let the constructor decide whether to copy/move the data, the operator unconditionally moves the result.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `DSString& DSString::operator=(DSString rhs) { DSString tmp(std::move(rhs)); std::swap(data, tmp.data); return *this; }`  Efficiently handles both copy assignment and move assignment and self-assignment protection.

Comment: I would use std string but we are not supposed to use the std string library at all

Answer (score 1):

I started with Remy's version. My version is more NULL-safe and shows how to use initializer lists in your constructors.

```
DSString::DSString() : data(nullptr)
{
}

DSString::DSString(const char* d) : data(nullptr)
{
    if (d != nullptr) {
        data = new char[strlen(d) + 1];
        strcpy(data,d);
    }
}

DSString::DSString(const DSString &src) : data(nullptr)
{
    if (src.data != nullptr) {
        data = new char[strlen(src.data) + 1];
        strcpy(data, src.data);
    }
}

DSString::~DSString()
{
    if (data != nullptr) {
        delete[] data;
        data = nullptr;
    }
}

DSString & DSString::operator=(const DSString &rhs)
{
    // This if protects against self-assignment.
    if (&rhs != this)
    {
        DSString tmp(rhs);
        std::swap(data, tmp.data);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: If you are going to teach the OP about language features like initialization lists, then you could take it a step further by setting `data` to `nullptr` right in the class declaration itself, removing the explicit default constructor and `default` it, and have the other constructors delegate to the compiler-generated default constructor. And there is no need to check `data` for `nullptr` when calling `delete[]`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's also not necessary to do data = nullptr in the destructor, but I do it anyway because I like to keep my objects in a proper state, even during destruction. Is it necessary? No. But it makes me feel better to always null-out my pointers when I free them. As for the first part of what you've said -- show him how. I've never done that.

Comment: "*I've never done that*" - Like this: `class DSString { private: char *data = nullptr; public: DSString() = default; ...};` ... `DSString::DSString(const char* d) : DSString() { ... }` ... `DSString(const DSString &src) : DSString() { ... }`